# How to store file and retrive it correctly with moodle file api?

Tags: api, file, plugins, save, moodle

i'm programming a mod activity for moodle which load files and show'em to any student who can access to the course.

The problem is that handing files in moodle is damn hard.

this is what i have done so far:

option page with importers

```
$mform->addElement('filepicker', 'slidesyncmedia', get_string('slidesyncmedia', 'slidesync'), null, array('maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => '*'));

$mform->addElement('filemanager', 'slidesyncslides', get_string('slidesyncslides', 'slidesync'), null, array('subdirs' => 0, 'maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'maxfiles' => 50, 'accepted_types' => array('*') ));
```

after submit the files are stored in draft
and everything is loaded in another page that save all on db

```
if ($draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('slidesyncmedia')) {
        file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $context->id, 'mod_slidesync', 'slidesyncmedia', 0, array('subdirs' => 0, 'maxfiles' => 1));
    }
    if ($draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('slidesyncslides')) {
        file_save_draft_area_files($draftitemid, $context->id, 'mod_slidesync', 'slidesyncslides', 0, array('subdirs' => 0, 'maxfiles' => 50));
    }
```

in the end i use again the first page in another place (if files are there, then shows them)

```
            $fs = get_file_storage();
        if ($files = $fs->get_area_files($context->id, 'mod_slidesync', 'slidesyncslides', '0', 'sortorder', false)) {
            // Look through each file being managed
            foreach ($files as $file) {
            // Build the File URL. Long process! But extremely accurate.
            $fileurl = moodle_url::make_pluginfile_url($file->get_contextid(), $file->get_component(), $file->get_filearea(), $file->get_itemid(), $file->get_filepath(), $file->get_filename());
            echo $fileurl;
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>Please upload an image first</p>';
        }
```

this make an url but if clicked moodle says that file does not exist
mysite.com/pluginfile.php/53/mod_slidesync/slidesyncslides/0/Koala.jpg

in the db the file are correctly saved!!!
    53  mod_slidesync   slidesyncslides     0   /   Koala.jpg

what i'm missing?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

A long time passed but I was working on a plugin and had the same problem.
I manage to solve it.

To provide the file you need to create the:
function MYPLUGIN_pluginfile($course, $cm, $context, $filearea, $args, $forcedownload, array $options=array())

Here is the example function: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API#Serving_files_to_users

Remember change the last call to send_file to send_stored_file in Moodle 2.3+